# PySpark filter using startswith from list

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, filter

I have a list of elements that may start a couple of strings that are of record in an RDD. If I have and element list of "yes" and "no", they should match "yes23" and "no3" but not "35yes" or "41no". Using PySpark, how can I use `startswith` to match elements in list or tuple.

An example DF would be:

```
+-----+------+
|index| label|
+-----+------+
|    1|yes342|
|    2| 45yes|
|    3| no123|
|    4|  75no|
+-----+------+
```

When I try:

```py
Element_List = ['yes', 'no']
filter_DF = DF.where(DF.label.startswith(tuple(Element_List)))
```

The resulting df should look something like:

```
+-----+------+
|index| label|
+-----+------+
|    1|yes342|
|    3| no123|
+-----+------+
```

Instead, I get the error:

> ```
> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o250.startsWith. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method startsWith([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

It looks like `startsWith` can't be used with any type of list. Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Compose expression like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
from functools import reduce

element_list = ['yes','no']

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["yes23", "no3", "35yes", """41no["maybe"]"""],
    "string"
).toDF("location")

starts_with = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x | y,
    [col("location").startswith(s) for s in element_list], 
    lit(False))

df.where(starts_with).show()
# +--------+
# |location|
# +--------+
# |   yes23|
# |     no3|
# +--------+
```

Comment: Note: this syntax also supports negative filtering
i.e. df.where(~starts_with) will select items that do not start with the elements from element_list.

Answer (score 3):

I feel best way to achieve this is with native PySpark function like `rlike()`. `startswith()` is meant for filtering the static strings. It can't accept dynamic content. If you want to dynamically take the keywords from list, the best bet can be creating a regular expression from the list as below.

```py
# List
li = ['yes', 'no']
# frame RegEx from the List
# in this case strings starting with yes/no i.e. "^(yes|no)"
reg_str = r"^("+ "|".join(li) + ")"
```

Custom UDFs or working with RDD functions might work, but usage of custom UDFs might hinder the performance.

Below is the complete working example.

```py
#Test Dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["yes23", "no3", "35yes"],
    "string"
).toDF("label")

# List
li = ['yes', 'no']
# frame RegEx from the List
# in this case strings starting with yes/no i.e. "^(yes|no)"
reg_str = r"^("+ "|".join(li) + ")"

#Filter dataframe with RegEx
df.filter(df.label.rlike(reg_str)).show()

# +--------+
# |label   |
# +--------+
# |   yes23|
# |     no3|
# +--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

When the elements in the list are of the same length, we can do this:

```py
element_list = ['ye', 'no']
df = df.filter(F.col('label')[0:2].isin(element_list))
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'yes342'),
     (2, '45yes'),
     (3, 'no123'),
     (4, '75no')],
    ['index', 'label'])
df.show()
# +-----+------+
# |index| label|
# +-----+------+
# |    1|yes342|
# |    2| 45yes|
# |    3| no123|
# |    4|  75no|
# +-----+------+

element_list = ['ye', 'no']
df = df.filter(F.col('label')[0:2].isin(element_list))

df.show()
# +-----+------+
# |index| label|
# +-----+------+
# |    1|yes342|
# |    3| no123|
# +-----+------+
```